# Raise XLRDError - Indicando nome do Sheet_name Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, concatenação-de-string, dataframe

Bom dia.
Estou iniciando com Python e estou com um problema.
Tenho N arquivos em Excel e preciso ler o sheet_name de cada um indicando o seu nome, o code que tenho até o momento é esse:

```
os.chdir("work path")
fileLista = glob.glob('*.xls')
arqFine= pd.DataFrame()
for arquivo in fileLista:
    df = pd.read_excel(arquivo, sheet_name = ["sheet do arquivo um ","sheet do arquivo dois","sheet do arquivo tres"], skiprows=1).split(',')
    arqFine= pd.concat([arqFine,df])
    arqFine.columns = arqFine.columns.str.strip()
```

Quando faço isso ele me retorna o erro: 'Raise XLRDError('No sheet named <%r>' % sheet_name)'
Não estou entendo o motivo de retornar esse erro, sendo que o nome do Sheet é exatamente isso.
E quando eu coloco o "sheet = 1" me retorna informações, porém não as que eu quero.
Alguém pode me ajudar a entender o problema? 
Obrigada.

Comment: Os nomes as planilhas estão corretos?

Comment: Sim, todos os nomes das planilhas estão corretos, eu até tentei renomear para fazer um teste, porém continua dando o mesmo erro.